# ConnectionResetError: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a script to download a group of files. I successfully completed this and it's working decently. Now I have tried adding a dynamic printout of the progression of the download.

For small downloads (it's of .mp4 files by the way) such as 5MB, the progression works great and the file closes successfully, thus resulting in a complete and working downloaded .mp4 file. For larger files, such as 250MB and above, it does not work successfully, I get the following error:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
import urllib.request
import shutil
import os
import sys
import io

script_dir = os.path.dirname('C:/Users/Kenny/Desktop/')
rel_path = 'stupid_folder/video.mp4'
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
url = 'https://archive.org/download/SF145/SF145_512kb.mp4'
# Download the file from `url` and save it locally under `file_name`:

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(abs_file_path, 'wb') as out_file:

    eventID = 123456

    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    length = resp.getheader('content-length')
    if length:
        length = int(length)
        blocksize = max(4096, length//100)
    else:
        blocksize = 1000000 # just made something up

    # print(length, blocksize)

    buf = io.BytesIO()
    size = 0
    while True:
        buf1 = resp.read(blocksize)
        if not buf1:
            break
        buf.write(buf1)
        size += len(buf1)
        if length:
            print('\r[{:.1f}%] Downloading: {}'.format(size/length*100, eventID), end='')#print('\rDownloading: {:.1f}%'.format(size/length*100), end='')
    print()

    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

This works perfectly with small files, but larger ones I get the error. Now, I do NOT get the error, however, with larger files if I comment out the *progress* indicator code:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(abs_file_path, 'wb') as out_file:

    # eventID = 123456
    # 
    # resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    # length = resp.getheader('content-length')
    # if length:
    #     length = int(length)
    #     blocksize = max(4096, length//100)
    # else:
    #     blocksize = 1000000 # just made something up
    # 
    # # print(length, blocksize)
    # 
    # buf = io.BytesIO()
    # size = 0
    # while True:
    #     buf1 = resp.read(blocksize)
    #     if not buf1:
    #         break
    #     buf.write(buf1)
    #     size += len(buf1)
    #     if length:
    #         print('\r[{:.1f}%] Downloading: {}'.format(size/length*100, eventID), end='')#print('\rDownloading: {:.1f}%'.format(size/length*100), end='')
    # print()

    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? This is the last part of my project and I would really like to be able to see the progress. Once again, this is Python 3.5. Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: I don't understand: you read from `resp` AND from `response` ? what for? Once you've written into `buf` completely, it seems that you're done? or am I mistaken? you could write directly to `out_file` BTW.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't know what I'm doing. But if I don't include `shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)` then the downloaded file remains 0 bytes.

Comment: just try `out_file.write(buf1)` instead of `buf.write(buf1)` in your loop. You don't need that `io.BytesIO` object.

Comment: And with that, would I still need `shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)` or should it work properly?

Comment: no, no need to `copyfileobj`. It would be already copied.

Comment: The error you see is because the server closed the connection; I would guess due to a timeout, which would be caused by your code not processing the packets already received in a timely manner. I suspect that trying to keep the entire (250+ MB) file in RAM (in your BytesIO object) is a cause of the problem. Just write the received data to the file as you receive it as earlier comments suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're opening your url twice, once as `response` and once as `resp`. With your progress bar stuff, you're consuming the data, so when the file is copied using `copyfileobj`, the data is empty (well maybe that is inaccurate as it works for small files, but you are doing things twice here and it is probably the orgin of your problem)

To get progress bar AND valid file do this:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(abs_file_path, 'wb') as out_file:

    eventID = 123456

    length = response.getheader('content-length')
    if length:
        length = int(length)
        blocksize = max(4096, length//100)
    else:
        blocksize = 1000000 # just made something up


    size = 0
    while True:
        buf1 = response.read(blocksize)
        if not buf1:
            break
        out_file.write(buf1)
        size += len(buf1)
        if length:
            print('\r[{:.1f}%] Downloading: {}'.format(size/length*100, eventID), end='')#print('\rDownloading: {:.1f}%'.format(size/length*100), end='')
    print()
```

Simplifications done to your code:

- only one `urlopen`, as `response`
- no `BytesIO`, directly write to `out_file`

Comment: I see what you mean now by the resp and response, thank you greatly for the help!